Group makes movie in protest against Hollywood
I remember seeing this movie from when I was young about a group of people making a movie (within a movie) which was made in a protest against (this is what it's about) hollywood.
People in the movie do not fake deaths, they die for real and such. I also remember a part where they present that Forrest Gump 2: Gump Again is being filmed. I hope I am making myself clear.

What country, language, genre and age is this movie?

I agree, extra details are most welcome. Luckily, this movie is quite distinct (fun, too).

Kevin Nealon's "I only take the roles I'm offered" is genius.

John Waters' wild satire Cecil B. Demented from 2000 with Melanie Griffith:

An insane independent film director and his renegade group of teenage filmmakers kidnap an A-list Hollywood actress and force her to star in their underground film.

At some point, the group invades the set of the Forrest Gump sequel "Gump Again" and wreak havoc. Here's the trailer:



